# Mysql query different group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

Hello i have a products table that contains normal products and configurable product

It has a basic stucture of:

- id
- name
- price
- configurable ('yes', 'no')
- id_configuration

Normal products have configurable no and 0 as id configuration, and configurable products have it set to yes and have the same id_configuration value.

The current query is:

```
SELECT `products`.* 
FROM `products`, `categories`, `product_categories` 
WHERE `categories`.`id` = 23 AND 
      `products`.`id` = `product_categories`.`id_product` AND 
      `categories`.`id` = `product_categories`.`id_category` AND 
      `products`.`active` = 'yes' 
ORDER BY `pos_new` ASC, `created` DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

I was wondering if there is a way to group by id_configuration, but only for the configurable products. The reason is that i want only one of the configuration products to show in search.
I was thinking i could do a join, but was wondering if there is a way to do some kind of special group by.
For example for configurable yes the field should be id_configuration otherwise it should be  the id field

Thanks a lot for any sugestions

Comment: You have a syntax error in your query: `... AND ORDER BY ...`. Guess the `AND` should be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CASE statement in the GROUP BY clause, and group by id_configuration if configurable is 'yes', or by id, which is unique (and therefore the equivalent of not grouping) if not.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` 
GROUP BY CASE `configurable` WHEN 'yes' THEN `id_configuration` ELSE `id` END
```

Comment: +1 for leading me to a better answer for my particular problem. I now have a query that performs a fairly complex query (multiple joins) to get to a suitable "GROUP BY" token for a row.